# Wordpress MariaDB Transaction committed, but not persisted

Tags: python, woocommerce, sqlalchemy, transactions, mariadb

I'm running a Plesk Server with a Wordpress/Woocommerce site backed by MariaDB.
I have some Python scripts using sqlalchemy/pymysql.
They're updating the products directly in the database, since the API is fairly slow and at times we have to touch metadata of >25k products.

Here's the problem:
I have a single transaction that does an `UPDATE` of a single postmeta field of a single product.
I call `commit()` explicitly. The return value tells me that one row was updated, no errors.
I check the audit log and see

```
8803221 Query   SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 1113875 AND meta_key = '_stock'
        8803221 Query   SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 1113875 AND meta_key = '_stock_status'
        8803221 Query   UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE post_id = 1113875 AND meta_key = '_stock_status'
        8803221 Query   SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 1113875 AND meta_key = '_lieferzeit'
        8803221 Query   SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 1113875 AND meta_key = '_manage_stock'
        8803221 Query   SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 1113875 AND meta_key = '_backorders'
        8803221 Query   COMMIT
        8803221 Query   ROLLBACK
```

Good, there's the COMMIT, followed by a ROLLBACK. That ROLLBACK I see after every transaction so I assume it's sqlalchemy clearing the transaction/session after it's done. But in any case, it was committed before that ROLLBACK.

Now I check the Database directly and see: The UPDATE didn't make it and there's still the old value inside.

If I run the UPDATE manually, it makes it through right away.

What's going on here?

- Used plain pymysql
- Used sqlalchemy
- Triple-Checked queries and Code
- Checked audit logs and general logs of MariaDB
- ran mysql_upgrade --force

Comment: Is the transaction that checked the result of the `UPDATE`, did that session start before or after the `COMMIT`?

Comment: HI @danblack I'm not sure I understand what you're meaning here.
I don't use the session manager.
With SQLAlchemy I used 
```
with db.engine.begin() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(...)
```
which should autocommit if nothing goes wrong.
And I used
```
with db.engine.connect() as conn:
  conn.execute(...)
  conn.commit()
```
.. explicitly calling commit.

Both yield the same logs in the database.